# wordpress how to get yesterday published post ids

Tags: wordpress

Is there any function to get yesterday published all post ids?
I always need yesterday or specific days post ids.

Example: today is: 01/04/2017 , i need all published post ids which published on 31/03/2017

Answer (score 1):

> **Try this code.**

```
<?php
$today = getdate();
$y_posts_ids = array();
$agrs = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day'   => $today['mday'] - 1,
        ),
    ),
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $agrs );
if( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $y_posts_ids[] = get_the_ID();
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date parameters of `get_posts` to find this:

```
<?php
// Get the date pieces using the timezone you set in WordPress, minus one day
$yesterday = getdate( current_time() - DAY_IN_SECONDS );

// Query for posts from yesterday
$yesterdays_posts = get_posts( array(
  'date_query' => array(
    array(
      'year' => $yesterday[ 'year' ],
      'month' => $yesterday[ 'mon' ],
      'day' => $yesterday[ 'mday' ]
    )
  ),
  'nopaging' => true
) );
```

This will give you an array of post objects from yesterday. `nopaging` means "give me all of them". Now, you can iterate through the results. If you just need the IDs, you can add them to an array like this:

```
<?php
$yesterdays_posts_ids = array();
if( $yesterdays_posts ){
  foreach( $yesterdays_posts as $yesterdays_post ){
    $yesterdays_posts_ids[] = $yesterdays_post->ID;
  }
}
```